# Can Apache Camel unmarshal CSV records into a POJO using header names?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, spring-camel, bindy

I found several examples of [Apache Camel Bindy](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html) unmarshalling CSV records into POJOs using field position:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Person {

    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String name;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String address;
```

I have 50+ different CSV files that I want to unmarshall into the same POJO. Each file has a header. The header names remain constant between the files, but the field position varies. For example,

```
File1.csv
--------------------------- 
name,homeAddress,someOtherFields
bob,123 Any Street,data
 
File2.csv 
---------------------------
homeAddress,name,someOtherFields
321 XYZ Street,jill,data
 
File3.csv 
---------------------------
name,someOtherFields,homeAddress 
sue,data,123 Any Street
 
etc.
```

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Person {

    @DataField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;
    @DataField(columnName = "homeAddress")
    private String address;
```

But `columnName` seems to be used for ouptut only. Also, `pos` is required.

Comment: I'm afraid that your assumption is correct, it is only position-based right now. Feel free to create a ticket for this need